# What is the difference between heat and work

Tags: thermodynamics

If 700 J of work is applied onto a gas, and therefore the gas contracted 0.005 m^3 (from 0.01m^3), and the temperature stayed at a constant rate of 300 kelvin, then how come when pressure is added to the system (Not by adding more molecules, but instead by increasing the kinetic energy of the molecules by adding heat) until the system becomes adiabatic (The system has as much total energy as it did from the start), we don't say that the heat applied equals to 700J?

It would make perfect sense if 700J were added to a system, then in order for that system to return to the same state, 700J would be taken away.

Comment: "The system becomes adiabatic"- Adiabaticity is not a character of the system, but of a process. Do you mean changing the system isothermally so that it reaches the initial state again?
Then one would extract heat in the process, not supply heat, since in the first step of isothermal compression, the pressure inside the gas would have increased, not decreased.

Comment: Do you notice "WHY" the units of work and heat are same ?

Comment: Work is basically change in macroscopic Kinetic Energy of a system, in this case the piston. Heat is any energy other than work.

Comment: Both have units of Joules. Heat is energy which contains entropy, work is energy which is entropy free.